# How to get trace report of Outlook sending mail in external application?

Tags: outlook

Usually my ERP system has a feature, that you can rightclick on a bill or an order and say "send as email". You fill out a form, klick on send and a security warning appears:

**A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf. If this is unexpected, click Deny and verify your antivirus software is up-to-date.**

Then this ERP (Lexware) places an email in my outlook, including the bill or order as attachment.
The mail is there, but only very seldom also the attachment.

I tried to run both applications as administrator, same result. Also disableing my virusscanner produced the same result.

We have Windows 2008R2 (x64) and Outlook 2003 (32Bit). Both are on newest patches.

I would like to know how I can find out what is blocking the attachment. I don't find any logs. How can I trigger this myself with a script to send a mail over Outlook? I want to understand the process behind.

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound like a programming question. Make sure your system has an up-to-date anti-virus app installed - this way Outlook will not display security prompts.

Comment: It is NOT about the secutiry prompt, in fact your answer is incorrect, as Outlook2003 doesn't have the option to not have the security prompt if virus scanner is on current version and detected by windows. This starts with versions newer as 2003.

So why this is not a programming question, if I ask for how this process is working? Especially my subquestion "How can I trigger this myself with a script to send a mail over Outlook?"

I have this question open in a few other boards where nobody has responded anything usefull. So I try here to get an idea HOW THIS IS CODED.

Comment: Are you trying to modify your own code or change the behavior of another app (Lexware)? The former you can do, the latter you cannot.

Comment: I want to reproduce what Lexware does: Putting an email to Outlooks outbox including an attachment, a mailadress for the to field, a mail body, a mail headline.
Once I know how this works it is much easier to find out what is wrong.

Comment: You want to reproduce the security prompt? Just touch one of the protected properties, such as MailIetm.Body / SenderName / Recipients. etc.

Comment: No, I want to send a mail. This security prompt is not interresting, as it pops up if it works and if it fails. I only brought it up here in my question, becasue if somebody codes such stuff, he will directly know why it pops up. As I don't have any idea about how to access outlook by script, I would be happy about a little example script. I guess I could use vba?

I also would be happy, if I find out, that I might be able to catch this access to outlook and redirect it to my own script to directly place my mail on my mailserver on localhost.

Comment: How would you be able to intercept any COM calls by a third party app to Outlook unless create your own out-of-proc COM server and register it in the registry Oh, and you will also need to replicate the Outlook Object Model with its dozens of objects and thousands of methods.